# SceneKit crash on iPad Air 2

Tags: swift, ios8, scenekit

I am developing an iPad App using SceneKit. It is still under development, but I have a few users testing via TestFlight.

One user has an iPad Air 2 which is consistently crashing. The App works OK on my iPad Air, a number of iPad 2 devices and the iPad simulator.

Crash logs from the iPad Air 2 all state the crash is caused by 'gpus_ReturnGuiltyForHardwareRestart'. The offending thread does not link back to my code so I am unsure how to resolve this.

[image]

I do not at present have access to an iPad Air 2.

Any suggestions on how I can overcome this issue?

Many Thanks

Comment: update your device and then check.

Comment: Hi aBilal17, I asked the user in question to update to iOS 8.3 just before I posted this. I will see if that works, if not check the crash logs again.Thanks

Comment: Hi aBilal17, updating the device resolved the issue. If you want to add this as an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your device and then check.